# From the given set of Linear equations. Find all solutions and the Rank of the matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification

Question :

Write the following system of equations :

$$\begin{bmatrix}
x_1+x_2+2x_3=4 \\ 3x_1+2x_2+x_3=7
\end{bmatrix}$$

in the form $A\vec x = \vec b$. Find all the solutions. Determine the rank of A.

---

My answer :

$$  \,\,\,\, \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 2 & 1
\end{bmatrix} }_{\text { 2 by 3 Matrix}}~~ \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\ x_2 \\ x_3
\end{bmatrix}}_{\text{3 by 1 Matrix}} = \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
y_1 \\ y_2
\end{bmatrix}}_{\text{2 by 1 Matrix}}$$
$$A\cdot \vec x= \vec b$$

Solving second part of the Question :

$$\tag{1}R_2-3R_1 \rightarrow R_1$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}
x_1+x_2+2x_3=4 \\ 0-x_2-5x_3=-5
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\tag{2}R_1+R_2 \rightarrow R_1$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}
x_1+0-3x_3=-1 \\ 0-x_2-5x_3=-5
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\tag{3} R_2 \div (-1) \rightarrow R_2$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}
x_1-3x_3=-1 \\ x_2+5x_3=5
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\ x_2\\x_3
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
-1+3t\\ 5-5t\\t
\end{bmatrix}  \, ,t \in \Bbb R$$

Last part of the Question :

Rank of a matrix, I have learned this way - firstly, convert the matrix into a upper triangular Matrix and then count the number of non-zero rows. The number of non-zero rows give the Rank$(A)$.

I think a $2$ by $3$ Upper triangular matrix would look like :

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1& a& b \\ 0& 1 & c
\end{bmatrix}$$

Making $A$ an upper triangular Matrix :

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 2 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$R_2-3R_1 \rightarrow R_2$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 2 \\ 0 & -1 & -5
\end{bmatrix} =  \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 1& 5
\end{bmatrix}}_{\text{ Both rows are non-zero rows}} $$

$$ Rank(A) = 2$$

---

Could you guys please help me validate my results, I’m slightly doubtful on rank of matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is correct for that reason.

Another way of justifying that is as follows: the rank of $A$ is the dimension of the range of the map $f_A\colon\Bbb R^3\longrightarrow\Bbb R^2$ whose matrix with respect to the standard bases is $A$. But $f_A(1,0,0)=(1,3)$ and $f_A(0,1,0)=(1,2)$. Since $\{(1,3),(1,2)\}$ spans $\Bbb R^2$, the dimension of the range is $2$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. Could you please suggest a reason for not choosing $f_A(0,0,1) = (2,1)$

Comment: Since the two other vectors that I got already span $\Bbb R^2$, there was no reason for me to take into account a third vector.

Comment: Alright, Thank you very much for your time and response

Comment: I'm glad I could help.